# When using AngularJS in a Firefox WebExtension, getting error "Chrome not defined"

Tags: angularjs, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to port my Chrome extension to Firefox WebExtension.  In a popup window, I am trying to open new window(for login), when user clicks on a button.

I am calling below function

```
chrome.tabs.create({"url" : "https://clipmystuff.com/login"});
```

error in browser toolbox

error : [image: chrome not defined]

Comment: Can you link us to your repository/code of you have so far. I'm pretty sure you are using `chrome.***` in a scope that it is not available. But if I can see that scope I can show you how to communicate with something that does have access to `chrome.***` or maybe we can even bring `crhome.***` into that scope.

Comment: Please do not put anything that is text in your question as an image. It makes it **much** harder to use/find/check etc. Copy the text and put it in as a code block (to preserve formatting).

Comment: @Noitidart I got chrome this issue working, this seems to be some issue with firefox developer version (48), but my code worked fine in firefox(46). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine in Firefox(version 45 or above), I was using Firefox for developers(48.1), I think this was something related to Firefox developer version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with FF 48 and [this tutorial for a WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension) where there are different members of `chrome` used, e.g. `chrome.extension.getURL()`.

The only thing I needed to solve the problem was to add these lines to `manifest.json`:

```
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "someid@mozilla.org",
        "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
},
```

This is apparently required to define the `chrome` object and prevent the error message `chrome not defined` to appear in the debugger.